# Access custom environment variable from Jenkins file

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to access system environment variable from my Jenkins file. I know that there are some predefined variables (e.g. `JOB_NAME` or `BUILD_NUMBER`), but I need to access custom environment variable which I set previously. What are the way to do this? It seems that `env.MY_VARIABLE` and `env['MY_VARIABLE']` but those don't work. I need this to have access to the variable which would be specified during the pipeline build inside a bash script. Probably there are more convenient ways to pass information from bash script to Jenkins file, which called this bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access environment variables like `${DB_ENGINE}` or `$DB_ENGINE` from bash or in your Groovy job/pipeline DSL script where `DB_ENGINE` is the custom environment variable you set.

Check [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/).